# How can I send some message from contract to address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, calldata, whisper

Is it possible? And if it is, how can I send some data from contract to address.
Something like

```
msg.sender.send.data("0x0")(value)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is something specifically for this purpose, which is called [Whisper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper)

> In a nutshell whisper is a communication protocol for DApps to communicate each other.

#### Example Usage

```
var shh = web3.shh;
var appName = "My silly app!";
var myName = "Gav Would";
var myIdentity = shh.newIdentity();

shh.post({
  "from": myIdentity,
  "topic": [ web3.fromAscii(appName) ],
  "payload": [ web3.fromAscii(myName), web3.fromAscii("What is your name?") ],
  "ttl": 100,
  "priority": 1000
});
```

Read [Whisper Overview](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Overview)

Comment: Yes, i've read about it. But can i use this wonderfull protocol from contract, and will it be like internal transaction or what? Can i catch it from, for example, etherscan, like internal transaction.