# How can i generate two equal signature with web3 and solidity?

Tags: web3js, erc-1155

i want to compare two signatures

one i created from web3

```
  const privateKey = //'address user'
  const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(address);
  const signature1 = web3.eth.accounts.sign(hash, privateKey);
```

and from solidity (erc1155) i am generating like this

```
bytes32 pack = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender));
 bytes32 signature2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",pack));
```

i want to compare but those signatures never are the same, how can i get the same signature?

```
signature1==signature2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the [ECDSA.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol) from OpenZeppelin to verify signature.
In solidity:

```
function _recoverSigner(bytes32 hash, bytes memory _signature) internal returns(address) { 
        return ECDSA.recover(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash)
            ),
            _signature
        );
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I think I misunderstood your question. The solution I propose above is a way to "Verify" signature1.

Why do you want to generate signature in solidity? In my opinion, we should not sign anything on solidity! Here is reason why: [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24371/99788)

The things that many projects on Ethereum do is to let the user sign a transaction (like the one that you created using web3 - "signature1"), then use that "signature1" and verify it on the smart contract:

In client's dapp

```
  const privateKey = //'address user'
  const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(address);
  const signature1 = web3.eth.accounts.sign(hash, privateKey);
```

In solidity - verify it:

```
function verifySignature(address _signer, bytes32 hash, bytes calldata _signature) public returns (bool){
  address signer = _recoverSigner(hash, _signature);
  return _signer == signer;
}
```

Here is an article about signing & validating: [Medium](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3)

Comment: with your code i would comparing like this signature1==signature2 ?

Comment: I have just updated the answer, please check it out

Comment: for this method (address _signer, bytes32 hash, bytes calldata _signature), from web3 i should send the hash and signature right?