# Do you spend gas to sign a message and send it to another client?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, signature, message

Let's say that I want to send the hash of a key to an entity and I want the entity to be sure that the hash could have come only from me.

It is possible to create a message with the hash of the key and then send it signed to the other entity?

Will this cost any gas?

Will a transaction be generated and mined in a block in the blockchain?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6824/52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign whatever you want off-chain with your private key and deliver it to someone else however you want (e.g. HTTP or email). This is how "payment channels" work without incurring transaction fees.